# Regexp problems, python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regexp to use in a parser. Specifically, I'd like to be able to parse strings formatted like so:

```
[SOME-WORD "Quoted string"]
```

Currently, I'm trying the following expression:

```
(?P<capital-item>
\[SOME-WORD(\ ?)\"
  (?P<quoted-string>\w+)
\"(\ ?)\])
```

I'm using python, and re.compile to get a scanner. Once compiled, the regexp doesn't match the example string I gave above. What am I messing up here?

Comment: Sorry, typo. That's not it

Comment: `\w` does not match the space between "Quoted" and "string". `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (no space).

Comment: Group names must be valid Python identifiers. Neither `capital-item` nor `quoted-string` are.

Comment: What do you wish to get out of it? An example result would be nice. Is "SOME-WORD" a static part of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '[SOME-WORD "Quoted string"]'
>>> pat = r'\[(?P<capitalitem>SOME-WORD)(\ ?)\"(?P<quotedstring>[\w\s]+)\"(\ ?)\]'
>>> re.search(pat, text).groupdict()
{'capitalitem': 'SOME-WORD', 'quotedstring': 'Quoted string'}
```